# Unity3D maintemplate.gradle kotlin dependencies

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, kotlin, gradle

I couldn't find something interesting on internet, that's why i ask for your help. I have a mainTemplate.gradle in my unity project, and inside of it i'm trying to apply kotlin-android plugin. The problem is that when i export my unity project to Android (or build the apk), it says that kotlin-android couldn't be find. Thanks in advance with your help.

Here is the mainTemplate.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
   }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dexOptions
            {
                // Prevent OutOfMemory with MultiDex during the build phase
                javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
            }

    defaultConfig
            {
                minSdkVersion 26
                targetSdkVersion 29

                ndk {
                    abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
                }
                versionCode 1
                versionName '0.1'

                resConfigs "fr", "en", "nl", "es", "ro", "pl"
            }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress '.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb', 'frenchtranslations.csv'
    }

    packagingOptions{
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
    }


    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'

            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.8'
        }
    }
    }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

    implementation(name: 'high-level-was-sdk-lib_9.20.3-1_debug', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'low-level-was-sdk-lib_6.20.3-1_release', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name: 'nr_api', ext:'aar')

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, it was pretty dumb.
Here is the modification. I needed to make some adjustments in unity after this. If anyone as questions or the same problem i can try to help you with this.

```
dendependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.11"
}
```

Comment: Hi @Orekia, I am trying to add some code to the maintemplategradle. I have never done this and can you please help me with it? Where is the file in the first place?